# How to call a static constructor to reassign the properties to their default?

Tags: c#, constructor, static

I have a `Settings` class to store the setting parameters as `Properties`. This class has its default `Property` variables and I want to set them default whenever I want. I had saw this usage in a video lesson but I can't remember clearly how he did this. Help please.

> **Settings.cs**

```
class Settings
{
    static Settings()
    {
        SaveDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        Type = ImageFormat.Png;
    }
    public static string SaveDir
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static ImageFormat Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

> **Form.cs**

```
Debug.WriteLine(Settings.SaveDir);
Settings.SaveDir = "path_to_another_directory";

Debug.WriteLine(Settings.SaveDir);
//In this line I expect that variables set their default
//but it stays the same
new Settings();

Debug.WriteLine(Settings.SaveDir);
```

This code doesn't work as I expected. How can I reassign these values calling `new Settings()`?

Comment: Well because they are `static`. The point for `static` items is to only have a single copy despite the number of instances.

Comment: You can't call the static constructor, however you could add a method named Reset() and reassign the initial values

Comment: Ok I have figured out changing the `static` access modifier into just `public` gives solution calling `new Settings()`. I misremembered like that `static` was used in the video lesson, so I forced myself to use `static`. Sorry for this stupid question.  Solution was simple than I thought. `Reset` is another approach also.

Comment: Beware, because now your class is no more static and changing the properties affects only that instance.

Comment: Although that does work, it's not an optimal solution, as a `Settings` object is created every time you want to reset. That's why using a static `Reset()` method is preferable.

Comment: @Steve, as long as the properties are `static`, doesn't it always returns the same value? I mean we can't call those properties using an instance of `Settings` like `(new Settings()).SaveDir`. This call doesn't give us anything and pop-up in `Auto-Completion`.

Comment: @AliTor, that's right. The properties will always return the same value because they are static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a static constructor as explained in the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

> A static constructor cannot be called directly

However nothing blocks you to write a method that *resets* the initial values

```
static Reset()
{
    SaveDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    Type = ImageFormat.Png;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the properties directly in the static constructor for `Settings`, try doing that in a different method, like this:

```
class Settings
{
    static Settings()
    {
        Reset()
    }
    public static void Reset()
    {
        SaveDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        Type = ImageFormat.Png;
    }
    public static string SaveDir
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static ImageFormat Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If you want to reset the settings, for example in `Form.cs`, call `Settings.Reset()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't call yourself a static constructor. Second, a static constructor can't be called twice. Here a [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) about it.

What about that.

```
class Settings
{
    static Settings()
    {
        LoadDefault();
    }
    public static void LoadDefault()
    {
        SaveDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        Type = ImageFormat.Png;
    }
    public static string SaveDir
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static ImageFormat Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then call Settings.LoadDefault() anywhere, anytime.